# Applying Butterworth High Pass Filter

Tags: python-2.7, signal-processing, highpass-filter

I have a problem with applying Butterworth High Pass Filter to my data. I would like to print filter for `Bx` and `By` matrix. As you can see I have both positive and negative values,

> how to apply `math.fabs()` to `Bx` and `By` to get only positive
>   values?

For my high pass filter I have those requirements:

Fc = 2 Hz

I would like to cut off values below 100 pT.

A part of my current code is:

```
plt.ylabel('Pico Tesle [pT]')
plt.xlabel('Time [ms]')
plt.grid()
plt.plot(time[51:-14], Bx[51:-14], label='Canal 1', color='r', linewidth=0.1, linestyle="-")
plt.plot(time2[1:-14], By[1:-14], label='Canal 3', color='b', linewidth=0.1, linestyle="-")
plt.legend(loc='upper right', frameon=False, )
```

And a chart is:
[image]

UPDATE: I have used this function to generate absolute values for Bx and By matrix.

```
plt.subplot(413)
np.absolute(fft1)
plt.plot(time[51:-14], np.absolute(fft1), color='r', linewidth=0.1, linestyle='-')
plt.grid()

plt.subplot(414)
np.absolute(fft2)
plt.plot(time2[1:-14], np.absolute(fft2), color='b', linewidth=0.1, linestyle='-')
plt.grid()
```

What I received thanks to that is that all my measurements (here are atmospheric discharges) are only in positive values (pT - picoTesla). First plot shows Canal 1, second plot shows Canal 3, and the third plot shows both Canals (Channels) combined.

No, I need (I guess) use High Pass Filter to cut off all measurements below 100 pT. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: A high-pass filter would reduce the amplitude of frequency components which are below the cutoff frequency. As it is your data shows variations at frequencies above your 2Hz cutoff, so they would hardly be affected by a high-pass filter. Did you instead wanted to use a low-pass filter? Otherwise `numpy.clip(np.absolute(fft1),0,100)` would limit the amplitude (but is a lossy operation if it's a concern).

Comment: Well thats a nice idea, but I cannot afford any loses in data. To be more precise I need to get all measurements which are above 100 pT, maybe my idea of using high pass filter is pointless, but nothing better came to my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used this method to solve the problem.

```
Wn = float(1)/HalfSampling
b, a = signal.butter(3, Wn, 'high', analog=False)
BxHPF = signal.filtfilt(b, a, Bxfft)
ByHPF = signal.filtfilt(b, a, Byfft)
plt.plot(BxTime, BxHPF, label='Canal 1', color='r', linewidth=0.5, linestyle="-")
plt.plot(ByTime, ByHPF, label='Canal 3', color='b', linewidth=0.5, linestyle="-")
```